# Can I change the default naming of Components in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I drop a textbox on a form, VS2012 will create a default name.  Is there anyway to change these defaults so they are closer to our coding standards?

I know I can change the name, but if I can automate that so much the better.

Comment: You'd have to replace the designer for the control.  There's little joy in doing that for *every* control in the toolbox.  The sane approach is to enforce coding standards not just on the code but also on the design-time names.  Especially on the design-time names I'd say.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Yes I guess that is the only option.  I was hoping there was template or something hidden somewhere :)>