# How does Visual Studio name controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

When an button is dragged and dropped on to the WinForms Designer, it automatically has the name `button1` and the next will be `button2`. How does this work? Is there any way to change the default naming behavior?

My Whole purpose is to get colFieldName instead of gridColumn1 and then changing its field name. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: What would you prefer as the default naming behavior other than the current one?

Comment: See this comment by Hans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734816/can-i-change-the-default-naming-of-components-in-visual-studio-2012#comment20619389_14734816

Answer (score 5):

> How does this work?

When you drag a control on the designer, Visual Studio determines the variable names in the current class and adds `1` until the variable is unique. (So it takes the class name `Button`, lower cases the first character (`button`), and then starts counting at `1`, so you get `button1`,  `button2`, etc.)

> Is there any way to change the default naming behavior?

No. Not for variables. For classes you have default templates and controls [can have a custom content when dropping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx), but as far as I know you cannot change the name of the variable.

Comment: @CodeCaster: For what part? It is hard to find documentation on a  non-existing function.

Comment: @Sri: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

you cant change the naming behavior, but if you going into the properties on the right hand side after selecting a button you can change the name to whatever you want it to be, it will then be referred to as this.

also it currently works like this When you drag a control on the designer, Visual Studio determines the variable names in the current class and adds 1 until the variable is unique.